# Ask if value CAPE and most unstable CAPE are Same

Tags: metpy

Metpy admin, I curious what  causes the value of CAPE and most unstable CAPE are same? Latest, I try to count CAPE and MCAPE use ERA5 data.

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming by "CAPE" you mean surface-based CAPE (if you're talking the MetPy functions, `cape_cin` needs to be passed explicitly a parcel profile to use), these two values will be the same when the "most unstable" parcel is the surface parcel.